# How to add summaries to seq2seq tutorial?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I'm working with [Seq2Seq example in TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/tutorials/seq2seq/index.html). I can run the training and see the outputs of perplexity on the development set. It's great!

I just want to add summaries (especially `scalar_summary` such as perplexity on dev set) to the event file and monitor them in TensorBoard. After [reading the documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/how_tos/summaries_and_tensorboard/index.html), I don't understand how to annotate [`translate.py`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/models/rnn/translate/translate.py#L27) with summary ops.

Can anybody can help me with simple pseudo-code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like `translate.py` doesn't create a TensorBoard summary log at all. (Part of the reason may be that much of the evaluation happens in Python, rather than in the TensorFlow graph.) Let's see how to add one.

1. You'll need to create a [`tf.train.SummaryWriter`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/train.html#SummaryWriter). Add the following before entering the training loop ([here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/3a955eb32d919bde8580ff53fb4e753a9579b8f5/tensorflow/models/rnn/translate/translate.py#L162)):

   ```
   summary_writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter("path/to/logs", sess.graph_def)
   ```
2. You'll need to create summary events for the perplexity in each bucket. These values are computed in Python, so you can't use the usual [`tf.scalar_summary()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/train.html#scalar_summary) op. Instead, you'll create a `tf.Summary` directly by modifying [this loop](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/3a955eb32d919bde8580ff53fb4e753a9579b8f5/tensorflow/models/rnn/translate/translate.py#L194):

   ```
   perplexity_summary = tf.Summary()

   # Run evals on development set and print their perplexity.
   for bucket_id in xrange(len(_buckets)):
     encoder_inputs, decoder_inputs, target_weights = model.get_batch(
         dev_set, bucket_id)
     _, eval_loss, _ = model.step(sess, encoder_inputs, decoder_inputs,
                                  target_weights, bucket_id, True)
     eval_ppx = math.exp(eval_loss) if eval_loss < 300 else float('inf')
     print("  eval: bucket %d perplexity %.2f" % (bucket_id, eval_ppx))

     bucket_value = perplexity_summary.value.add()
     bucket_value.tag = "peplexity_bucket)%d" % bucket_id
     bucket_value.simple_value = eval_ppx

   summary_writer.add_summary(perplexity_summary, model.global_step.eval())
   ```
3. You can add other metrics by constructing `tf.Summary` values yourself and calling `summary_writer.add_summary()`.

Comment: Hi mrry, Is there a way to add a summary about the encoder_state e.g. [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/seq2seq.py#L323). I tried to implement a VAE between encoder and decoder and print the KLD. However, it fails because (i guess) it cannot evaluate the sequences from the other buckets.